# HTML tables acting weird

Tags: html, css, html-table

So i've been sitting on this HTML table for a while but can't get the text to align.
[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJWBD.png) but all the text should be aligned. I really don't get it.

Table code below

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-354" src="http://www.yoganow.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MG_2007a-4.1.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></td>
<td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-354" src="http://www.yoganow.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MG_2240a-46.1.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></td>
<td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-354" src="http://www.yoganow.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/admin-ajax-300x151.jpeg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Yoga voor kinderen: Speels, uitdagend en in balans.</td>
<td> Yoga voor tieners is voor iedereen tussen de 12 en 16 jaar. Vol uitdaging.</td>
<td>Yoga zorgt voor evenwichtig leven.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, text cells are vertically aligned to the middle.

If you want it all aligned to the top, add this to your CSS:

```
td {vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: As far as I understood, he want to make the text to not exceed image's left and right limits.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to limit text with dimension of image. If images are 180px width, then you need to include text in span and define width 180 to the span. Also set `text-align: center` for `td` to make span text and image aligned in vertical direction.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-354" src="http://www.yoganow.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MG_2007a-4.1.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></td>
<td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-354" src="http://www.yoganow.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MG_2240a-46.1.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></td>
<td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-354" src="http://www.yoganow.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/admin-ajax-300x151.jpeg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>Yoga voor kinderen: Speels, uitdagend en in balans.</span></td>
<td><span>Yoga voor tieners is voor iedereen tussen de 12 en 16 jaar. Vol uitdaging.</span></td>
<td><span>Yoga zorgt voor evenwichtig leven.</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```